# Searching data in text file for output and convert to table dataframe

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

in advanced sorry if I have any mistake during reading my questions:
I'm working with Django and python for my website.

The process I need to read input from the user for searching the directory file that I want to read which is I take 2 input, input1, and input2.

I set the keyword in the variable if the keyword is matching I will print the next line.

**THIS IS MY TEXT FILE**

> `delay_index_time
>   775435
>   delay_index_time
>   456345
>   delay_index_time
>   4567867867868
>   delay_index_time
>   567867`

**Python Code In views.py**

```
def SearchBox(request):
    fullpath = ""
    input1= request.GET.get('input1')
    input2= request.GET.get('input2')
    input_combine = str(input1).upper() + "_" + str(input2)
    summary = '1A'
    search_string = 'delay_index_time'

    if input_Lot is None:
        return render(request, 'Output.html')

    else:

        path = "D:/file/" + str(input_combine) + "/" + summary
        with open(path) as input_data:
            for line in input_data:
                if search_string in line:

                    context = {

                         "output": (next(input_data))

                    }

                    return render(request, 'Output.html', context)
```

**Template HTML**

```
  <form id = "lol" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="GET" action="">

   <div class="input-group">
      <input style="left:260px; width:250px; top:-80px;" id="box1" name="input1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lot">
    <input style="left:270px; top:-80px; width:250px;" id="box2" name="input2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Operation">



    <div  style="left:540px; top:-101px;" class="input-group-btn">
      <a href="{% url 'Output' %}"><button id = "search_sub" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
{{ output|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

My issue is it only print the first line of the output which is:

> 775435

But the other 3 output not display.

> 456345
>
> 4567867867868
>
> 567867

**EXTRA QUESTION**

How if i want the output display in table form in one column on my website.

---

> ```
>                                      NEW QUESTION
> ```

---

> This is data in my text file.

1. I will display the string after I found 'id_' which is the id user.
2. Display the id user in one column.
3. Then, under id user got delay_index_time which I will display next line of the output.
4. But sometimes delay_index result will have more than one result.
5. I will zip it/combined in one table with 2 column.
6. It will display using a check box selection. if let's say user only want to view user id it will only display that. if the user ticks both of it in check box it will display both of it in the table.
7. For the check box, I have no idea on it. Sorry if I'm asking a lot of question :(

   ```
   id_A1
   delay_index_time
   s_7754
   s_7731
   id_A2
   delay_index_time
   mrs_7745
   id_A3
   delay_index_time
   s_77789
   id_A4
   delay_index_time
   s_7752
   ```

> This is my coding in views.py

```
    context = {}
    with open(path) as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if line.startswith('id_'):
                if 'output' in context:
                    context['output'].append(line.lstrip('id_').rstrip())

            if search_string in line:
                if 'output1' in context:
                    context['output1'].append(next(input_data).lstrip('s_').rstrip())

            context = {

                'output': [(line.lstrip('id_').rstrip())],
                'output1': [(next(input_data).lstrip('s_').rstrip())]

            }

          return render(request, 'Output.html', context)
```

> This is my templates

```
<div  class="container" style=" width:170px;">


    <table style="" class="table table-bordered">

        <thead class="success" >

        <th class="active"><b>Visual ID</b></th>

        {% for line in output1 %}
         <tr  class="success">

            <td>{{ line }}</td>

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        </thead>

         <thead class="success" >

        <th class="active"><b>Time Delay</b></th>

        {% for line in output %}
         <tr  class="success">

            <td>{{ line }}</td>

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        </thead>


    </table>
```

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeXFM.png)
[Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJait.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works for me.

```
context = {}
with open(path) as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if search_string in line:
            if 'output' in context:
                context['output'].append(next(input_data))
            else:
                context = {'output': [(next(input_data))]}
    return render(request, 'Output.html', context)
```

And to display output in a tabular form.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Output</th>
  </tr>
  {% for line in output %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{ line }}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you sadia. The code working very well to display all of the output. But the output not in a table format. Appreciate for your time to answer my questions  :D

Comment: For table borders use CSS. 
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

Comment: Hi Sadia, one last question if you free can you help me. if I have another statement. I want it to create a new column beside the existing one how to combine it with two column. I add the code at below of my question.

Comment: Yes, can you share the table with values.

Comment: Hi, Sadia, I already post under new question at above hope you can understand, and the output I already upload the image with table format.

Comment: You have made incorrect context response, it should be dict of user_id contains list of delay_index_time as per your data and requirement.

Comment: views.py:
    context = {}
    data = {}
    prev_key = ''
    with open(path) as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if line.startswith('id_'):
                prev_key = line.lstrip('id_').rstrip()
                data.update({line.lstrip('id_').rstrip(): []})
            elif line.startswith('s_'):
                if prev_key in data:
                    data[prev_key].append(line.lstrip('s_').rstrip())
    context = {'output': data}

Comment: Template:
<div  class="container" style=" width:170px;">
    <table style="" class="table table-bordered">
       <thead class="success" >
       <tr>
           <th class="active"><b>User Id</b></th>
           <th class="active"><b>Time Delay</b></th>
       </tr>
        {% for key, values in output.items %}
       <tr  class="success">
            <td rowspan={{ values|length|add:1 }}>{{ key }}</td>
            {% for value in values %}
                <tr><td>{{value}}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
       </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </thead>
    </table>
</div>

Comment: Hi Sadia, actually you can edit and my posted code or urs one. I have tried your code this is my real coding VIEWS -https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP6Gc.png TEMPLATES -
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4cmX.png

Comment: But on time delay it shows nothing it displays blank column while the user id working perfectly. Based on the time delay actually, if I found the time delay index time I will extract the next line output. It not similar to the user id which takes if startswith 'id_'

Comment: Correct the code indentation. Note that context should set out of the file open statement.

Comment: Yaa Sadia a lot of effort from you thank you so much, but the error still happen if you can see. when i select to display first statement it working, it will display the visual id. But if a user selects only to display time delay index in checkbox it displays nothing and it happens the same thing if a user wants to display both. TEMPLATES -https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJait.png VIEWS.py- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeXFM.png

Comment: You have provided incomplete information and your code has changed too. It is not working because you have changed if/else clause in views.py

Comment: Yaa, thanks Sadia. This questions closed, I able to make it dy :D Thank you for your effort I appreciate it :D Sorry for wasting your time to answer it. Thanks again.